# How to get Locale.getDisplayName() value to return non-English text?

Tags: java

The following unit test failed:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LocaleTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("lv"));
  }

  @Test
  public void displaysLatvianLocale() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("lv");
    String expected = "Latviešu";
    String actual = locale.getDisplayName();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void displaysRussianLocale() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
    String expected = "Krievu";
    String actual = locale.getDisplayName();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void displaysEnglishLocale() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    String expected = "Angļu";
    String actual = locale.getDisplayName();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

`displaysLatvianLocale` is ok. But the other two tests fail with:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Krievu]> but was:<[Russian]>
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Angļu]> but was:<[English]>
```

JRE doesn't have Latvian translations for `ru` and `en` and falls back to English.

Is it possible to add user-defined translations to `Locale.getDisplayName()`?

Comment: maybe this one will be useful for you, there is an example with thai symbols in the end https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html